# cmake: How to suppress "Entering directory" messages?

Tags: linux, makefile, cmake

I have a project with different sub-modules. Each sub-module has a `CMakeLists.txt` and I have a general `CMakeLists.txt` at the root of the project.

When I run `cmake --build [...]` or `make [...]`, it recursively builds sub-modules as expected but it prints verbose like this:

```
make[2]: Entering directory '/some/path/'
make[2]: Entering directory '/some/path/'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/some/path/'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/some/path/'
...
```

#### What I have tried

- Explicitly turn off cmake/make verbose by adding `set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE OFF)` in the general `CMakeLists.txt`.
- `make [...] --no-print-directory`
- `cmake [...] -- [...] --no-print-directory`

The `--no-print-directory` flag removes these messages as intended, but I used to not have to specify this flag in previous projects. I would prefer to avoid using this flag to get the same results as before.

#### Versions

`GNU Make 4.3`
`cmake version 3.16.4`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use

```
MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory
```

Described in the [GNU make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Options_002fRecursion)

Comment: Added `export MAKEFLAGS=--no-print-directory` to my `.zshrc` to have a user wide effect.

Comment: If you are using vscode cmake extension, adding` "cmake.buildToolArgs": ["--no-print-directory"]` to settings.json will solve the issue.

Comment: I think `--no-print-directory`  (two dashes).

Comment: Does not work for me, as I run cmake .. && $(MAKE) in a Makefile, where I set some restrictive MAKEFLAGS for that Makefile, and then unset MAKEFLAGS for the cmake-generated Makefile. My hack is to echo '$$(VERBOSE)MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory' >> Makefile between cmake and $(MAKE) but I'd like something better...