# Reverse-Recursive Makefile - Suppress entering/leaving directory messages

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I know there are many discussions here, why don't use recursive Makefiles. But not reverse. Use this concept (Reverse-Recursive) for usability purpose. With this system I only need **one** open shell for adding new or modified files to `git` and can also type `make` in the same path for rebuild the changed source and link them.

Short description to my Reverse-Recursive `Makefile` implementation. I have the following simplified tree here:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── subdir
│       ├── Makefile
│       └── subsubdir
│           └── Makefile
└── Makefile

3 directories, 4 files
```

Content from the Root-Makefile:

```
all:
    @echo 'Makefile-root: all'

arg1:
    @echo 'Makefile-root: arg1'

arg2:
    @echo 'Makefile-root: arg2'

.PHONY: all arg1 arg2
```

RR-Makefile: All other Makefiles in the sub-directories have the same content:

```
%::
    make -C .. $@

all:
    make -C ..

.PHONY: all
```

Output when I type `make` in `subsubdir`:

```
$ make
make -C ..
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test/dir/subdir'
make -C ..
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test/dir'
make -C ..
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test'
Makefile-root: all
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test/dir'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test/dir/subdir'
```

Output when I type `make` with an argument in `subsubdir`:

```
$ make arg1
make -C .. arg1
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test/dir/subdir'
make -C .. arg1
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test/dir'
make -C .. arg1
make[3]: Entering directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test'
Makefile-root: arg1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test/dir'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/krj/projects/XU-Loader/test/dir/subdir'
```

It's maybe only a cosmetic issue, but how can I suppress `Leaving/Entering` messages without to invoke `make` with the argument `--no-print-directory` in `subsubdir`?

```
$ make --no-print-directory
make -C ..
make -C ..
make -C ..
Makefile-root: all
```

Have tried to add `MAKEFLAGS += -no-print-directory` in each RR-Makefile but **breaks** the function of the recursion down to the root Makefile.

Comment: You provide a ton of detail but then when you get down to the actual question you just say "it breaks" which doesn't help at all.  Please provide the actual output you get and explain what is wrong with it.  I'm assuming that in your real implementation you use the correct option name `--no-print-directory` not the incorrect one you show in your question `-no-print-directory`.

Comment: Also note that, generally speaking, a recursive make should always be started with [`${MAKE}`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#MAKE-Variable) rather than `make`.

Comment: @G.M. In the source trees from my projects I use a variable name for `make`. Not direct MAKE, but an other none-standard name, which I use in my build system, similar to `Kbuild`.  This example was only simplified.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, I used `-no-print-directory` instead of `--no-print-directory`. First searched here on SO and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449472/cmake-how-to-suppress-entering-directory-messages?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top) first and tried that only. I think this SO answer should be corrected. But I wondering why `make` doesn't output an error message.

Comment: Well, you still haven't shown us any output so we can't actually say for sure.  But my suspicion is that the option string `-no-print-directory` is being interpreted as the short option `-n` (which means don't run anything) followed by the short option `-o` with the argument `-print-directory` (which means consider the file `-print-directory` to be very old).  Make, like most traditional POSIX tools, allow short options to be run together so `-nrR` is the same as `-n -r -R` etc.

Comment: Since it has not been mentioned yet: The Entering/Leaving messages are not purely cosmetic. Some editors use these messages to determine from the make output in which directory a file producing a compile error is located so the editor can quickly jump to the source file location of the compile error.

Answer (score 2):

It was an usage fault from me. I used `-no-print-directory` instead of `--no-print-directory`, because I searched first on SO for a similar question and found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60449472/cmake-how-to-suppress-entering-directory-messages?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top). Unfortunately don't investigaed the manual pages from GNU make.

With `--no-print-directory` this works, without any issues:

```
MAKEFLAGS += --no-print-directory

%::
    make -C .. $@

all:
    make -C ..

.PHONY: all
```

Comment: You can also use `-s`